# How to dynamically add a (HABTM) collection_select + associated text_field in a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dynamic, has-and-belongs-to-many, collection-select

For a personal invoicing app in rails I could use some advice on the following: In a new invoice form, how to dynamically add a new row consisting of a collection_select for `products` and an associated text_field for `amount` by clicking `add new product`?

Since one invoice has many products and a product has many invoices, I figured this is a HABTM relationship both ways. Therefore I have created the tables `invoices`, `products`, and their join table `invoices_products`.

I would like the `invoices/new` page to have a form where a user can use a collection_select to pick a product (all products are already preloaded in the `products` table) and fill in the amount in a text field behind it.
A user should be able to duplicate these two fields (collection_select and text_field) by clicking `add new product`, something like `RailsCast #403 Dynamic Forms 04:50`.

Now how would I go about doing that? And in what table would I put the data from the `amount` text_field, since there are multiple products per invoice so multiple amounts?

Any answer in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how many additional fields you want

A good tutorial for this can be found [here](http://pikender.in/2013/04/20/child-forms-using-fields_for-through-ajax-rails-way/)

---

**Ajax**

The right way would be to add the element dynamically with Ajax

This is tricky because it means you're not going to have the `form_builder` object available for the dynamically added items. Regardless, you can still do it with this code:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "new_field_path", to: "invoices#new_item"

#app/views/controller/index.html.erb
<%= ... form %>
<%= link_to "Add Field", new_field_path, remote: :true %>
```

---

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb
def new_item
   @invoice = Invoice.new
   @invoice.products.build
   render "new_item", layout: false
end

#app/views/invoices/new_item.html.erb
<%= form_for @invoice do |f| %>
    <%= render partial: "products_fields", locals: { f: f } %>
<% end %>

#app/views/invoices/_products_fields.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :products, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |p| %>
    <%= p.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Form**

```
#app/views/invoices/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @invoice do |f| %>
   <%= render partial: "products_fields", locals: { f: f } %>
   <%= link_to "Add Field", new_field_path, remote: :true %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Rich! I don't know much about Ajax yet but I'm going to check it out!